# How to get Minecraft crossplay working (PC/PS4)?

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition, ps4, windows-10

I'm trying to set up *Minecraft Bedrock Edition* to crossplay between my Windows 10 system and my PS4 so I can play with my two boys (we're in the same house).

The problem is that I have gotten everything working but we are not able to play together because we always show up as offline to each other.

I have the Windows 10 Bedrock Edition installed on my desktop computer, and the latest PS4 version installed on the console. Both work independently and we can play, just not together. I've paid for Playstation Plus (to allow multiplayer internet access etc) and set us up with distinct Xbox online profiles, logged in on each instance of the game, and are connected as friends.

Each of us can play (the boys playing split-screen or even solo), and me on my desktop. But then when we try and invite each other from the menu it says we have no online friends and from in-game, the only option is to invite the other as 'offline' (an invite that never comes through of course).

I'm out of options now and not sure what to do to make this work! I've paid for two copies of the game and spent hours checking and re-checking everything and am losing patience with it.

Is a LAN game an option in cross-play? What am I missing?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can PS4 join a PC Bedrock Edition world and how?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/400931/can-ps4-join-a-pc-bedrock-edition-world-and-how)