# Can PS4 join a PC Bedrock Edition world and how?

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition, pc, ps4

I just bought *Minecraft: Bedrock Edition* on PC and I am trying to join my boyfriend on PS4. I was trying to look it up, but nothing is popping up on how to join cross-platform. Are we even able to join each other? If so, how?

Comment: For the close votes: Joining someone else playing the game is different than joining a server. Cross play is supported out of the box, while joining servers is not.

Comment: Same question, though has no answers: https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/389988/how-to-get-minecraft-crossplay-working-pc-ps4

Comment: Have you purchased the game from Microsoft store?

Answer (score 2):

First, go to the "Play" then "Friends" section.
Then, click "Add Friend".

You need to put in what they see over their character in the main menu here:

[image: Character on Main Menu]

After that, you should be able to join worlds with them.

If this for some reason doesn't work, try joining a small server that won't have that many people. After this, find each other on the list in the pause menu and you can add each other as a friend from there.

Answer (score 0):

### Yes

Yes, you are able to join your boyfriend. In fact, the whole reason that the Bedrock Edition exists is for that reason: cross-platform!

All you need to do is add your boyfriend's username by adding him as a friend. After that, create a world (most settings other than the multiplayer section don't matter).

Once it is done loading, pause the game, then on the top left, click "Invite Players". If your boyfriend is added as your friend, then select him. Sometimes the invite might take a second for it to pop up for him, so I would recommend inviting him a couple of times.